# Can i have two DHCP wifi router for one LAN

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, dhcp-server

I have 9(nine) **tp-link tl-mr3420** `router` in one **LAN** with one **WAN** **IP** address.

Can I configure two of them as a **DHCP server** for one **LAN**?

Comment: Related Canonical post you should read on this topic: https://serverfault.com/questions/368512/can-i-have-multiple-dhcp-servers-on-one-network

Answer (score 3):

Strictly responding to your question (which is missing a lot of data).  Sure you can have two DHCP servers on a single LAN.  All you have to do is to make sure that the DHCP pools do not overlap.  At times, you may experience service disruption if the wireless device needs to obtain a new address from the second pool upon a roam.  Other than that, it should work.